# PHP Direct File Download

Tags: php, file, download

I would like to download a file from a web server which has been pushed with "direct download" by using the header `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");`

I am using the following PHP code, but my download is 0 byte.

Can you help me out?
Kindest regards!

```
$uploaddir = getcwd();
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . "/". basename($_POST["filename"]);


// Initialize a file URL to the variable 
$url = $_POST["fileurl"]; 

// Initialize the cURL session 
$ch = curl_init($url); 

// Inintialize directory name where 
// file will be save 
$dir = $uploaddir; 

// Use basename() function to return 
// the base name of file  
$file_name = basename($_POST["filename"]); 

// Save file into file location 
$save_file_loc = $dir . "/" . $file_name; 

// Open file  
$fp = fopen($save_file_loc, 'wb'); 

// It set an option for a cURL transfer 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

// Perform a cURL session 
curl_exec($ch); 

// Closes a cURL session and frees all resources 
curl_close($ch); 

// Close file 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Is it a cache issue? Did you already check with incognito mode? I just tried your URL and it works fine. Got  some, 20-30, rows data file.

Comment: when I open the URL in the browser everything works fine but the above code returns 0 bytes ...